# disable shift key on startup in ms-access

Tags: ms-access, keyboard-shortcuts, vba

Problem: In MS Access you can hold the **shift key** when **opening** a database in order to **bypass Startup** options and the **AutoExec** Script. I want to **disable this permanently**.

First of all I know this has been answered on numerous other sites, however I could not find a question about it here, but I have a slightly different need.The solutions I found were focused on placing invisible buttons to re-enable the shift-key shortcut with passwords etc.

I want a **very simple solution**. I want a script I can add to my AutoExec script to disable the shift-key shortcut or something like that.

I **DO NOT need a way to re-enable** the shift-key shortcut.

The **simplest**, most **secure**, and **easiest** way to do this is preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the Access VBE help file under AllowBypassKey? Code for this is provided right there in the help file. As to security, that's a different kettle of fish, since anybody with a little programming knowledge could disable your settings, even if you've secured your front end using Jet user-level security.

Comment: no sorry, i didn't even know there was a help file. I use access very little and do visual basic in access even less. Do mostly .net and MsSql type stuff. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have always used this bit of code

```
Function SetBypass(rbFlag As Boolean, File_name As String) As Integer
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    On Error GoTo SetBypass_Error
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase(File_name)
    db.Properties!AllowBypassKey = rbFlag
setByPass_Exit:
    MsgBox "Changed the bypass key to " & rbFlag & " for database " & File_name, vbInformation, "Skyline Shared"
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Exit Function


SetBypass_Error:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    If Err = 3270 Then
        ' allowbypasskey property does not exist
        db.Properties.Append db.CreateProperty("AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, rbFlag)

        Resume Next
    Else
        ' some other error message
        MsgBox "Unexpected error: " & Error$ & " (" & Err & ")"
        Resume setByPass_Exit
    End If
End Function
```

You pass it a filename and then say if you want the bypass key to be enabled or not.

The problem is that anyone else with this code can use it to “Unlock” your database and enable the bypass key.

The only way I can think to get around this would be to only give the users the runtime version of access

Comment: where/how do I run this script? and if I did this and made the access file read-only would that stop them from changing it back?

Comment: You can put it in a separate “Utility” database or you can put it in a module on your existing ones. You call it like this

SetBypass False, "C:\MyDatabase.mdb"

Comment: worked great. I put this code in a new Module and put that line of code in my form load function. The form is loaded by the autoexec script so it should run every time the database is opened.

Comment: A question, how do you add this to the autoexec script ?