# Generating an event upon un-hiding the navigation pane

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to know if it is possible to execute code in the event event that the user tries to activate the navigation pane.  In short, my database is set up to hide the navigation pane and keep the users away from it's underlying tables. In the event the user presses F11 i would like to generate code to unlink (delete) the tables which feed the database.  Is there an event that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no event raised within Access for this. You should consider clearing the **Display Navigation Pane** and **Use Access Special Keys** options in File->Options->Current Database.

With these options set, the Navigation pane will be hidden at the start and you cannot invoke it with F11. However, a user can get around this by holding down shift when first opening the database. To disable the **Bypass Key**, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185042/2548338.