# Can't edit existing form in MS Access, opening .accdb file opens form automatically with no ribbons or menus

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm very new to MS Access 2016 and my boss has asked me to add a simple "add new employee" button to an existing form made by a previous intern. I have access to both an .accdb and an .accdr file. I also have access to the SQL Server where the form's database and tables are located.

However, I haven't found a way to edit the form. Whenever I try to open the .accdb file, it automatically opens the form employees here use daily, but there are no ribbons or menus other than a stripped down version of File with only Print, Privacy Options, and Close in it.

I have tried using different workstations, earlier versions of Access, and made sure I'm the only one that has the .accdb file open. I've tried using Shift bypass several times to no avail. Privacy Options is empty with only a checkbox for helping improve the program by sending data back Microsoft. F11, Alt-F11, and Ctrl-G don't do anything either. I also can't open MSACCESS.EXE by itself without it spitting a "Cannot find specified database" error.

Is there anything else I could do to be able to edit or design the form?

Comment: Unless you are asking about programming tools used with Access (e.g. vba, SQL), general software questions are off topic for stack overflow. You might have better luck getting an answer to this type of question at [superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Ah, sorry about that! I'll definitely go ahead and ask this question on superuser.

Comment: Try the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184455/disable-shift-key-on-startup-in-ms-access on the .accdb

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but how would I go ahead and run the script from the answer you linked @Andre? When opening Access I'm unable to access a VBA Immediate Window or anything. I've also just tried creating a new .accdb from scratch, but I'm having the same issue as with the existing .accdb file. I'm also getting a "Potential Security Risk" warning on any .accdb file I try to open.

Comment: The code goes into a new module in a new database. Then Ctrl+G and run `SetBypass True, "D:\myLockedDB.accdb` (paste, adapt path, hit Enter)

Comment: Um, are you sure you have a full version of Access installed, not a runtime version? -- Edit: re-reading your question, that sounds very much like a runtime version.

Comment: @Andre I was not aware of it before, but after checking just now, yes, the version of Access 2016 installed on my workstation is a runtime version. Since I'm getting the same warnings on other workstations, I guess they are also running runtime versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Um, are you sure you have a full version of Access installed, not a runtime version? -- Edit: re-reading your question, that sounds very much like a runtime version

After checking the different workstations, they were indeed all running runtime versions of Access, which is why I couldn't edit anything.